# How to build Parser in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

```
data Expr   = ExprNum Double -- constants
            | ExprVar String -- variables
            | ExprAdd Expr Expr
            | ExprSub Expr Expr
            | ExprNeg Expr -- The unary '-' operator
            | ExprMul Expr Expr
            | ExprDiv Expr Expr
            deriving Show
```

This is my user define data type. I want to handle arithmetic expression like `(2+3 *4 - x)` using above data types without using `buildExpression` parser. What can I do?

Please help me.It should handle operator precedence.

Comment: Is there a reason we can't use buildExpressionParser? I assume this means you are using parsec. Do you know how to left-factor your grammar so that it is actually valid?

Comment: "`buildExpression` parser" probably refers to [this Parsec module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Expr.html).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we want to build an `addsub` level parser. We'd like to say that (ignoring actual returning of correct values and just focusing on the raw parsing)

```
addsub = muldiv >> oneOf "+-" >> muldiv
```

This doesn't really work. But we can left factor this as

```
addsub = muldiv >> addsub'
addsub' = many $ oneOf "+-" >> muldiv
```

Where we assume `muldiv` is a parser for just multiplication and division which you can write in a similar manner.

That is, instead of using the grammar

```
addsub = addsub (+-) muldiv | muldiv
```

We use the slightly more complicated, but actually usable by Parsec:

```
addsub = muldiv addsub'
addsub' = (+-) muldiv addsub' | Nothing
```

Which we can of course refactor the latter into a `many` which gives us a list of expressions that we would add. You could then convert that to whatever form you want, such as `(Add a1 (Add a2 (Add a3)))`.