# datatype conversion without using buildExpressionParser

Tags: haskell, parsec, haskell-platform

I am stuck at a point in converting a expression entered by the user to my own datatype

I did it using `biuldExpressionParser` , but using simple parser and recursion  I did as follows

```
 openBrace = char '('

 closeBrace :: GenParser Char st Char
 closeBrace = char ')'

bracketExpr = do
            spaces >> openBrace
            expr <- expressionParser
            spaces >> closeBrace
            return expr
```

`bracketExpr` will return the entered expression in my own datatype

to convert it into my datatype I did for negation,if expression is a number or a variable as follows:

```
 expressionParser = negate1
                 <|> number
                 <|> variable
                 --<|> addition
                 <?> "simple expression"

 negate1 :: Parser Expr
 negate1 = do{ char '-'
             ;ds <-  number
             ;return (ExprNeg (ds) )
             }
        <?> "negate"

variable :: Parser Expr
variable = do{ ds<- many1 (letter <|> digit)
             ; return (ExprVar ds)}
         <?> "variable"

number :: Parser Expr
number = do{ ds<- many1 digit
           ; return (ExprNum (read ds))}
          <?> "number"
```

To do the same for addtion I tried by seperating the expression using `sepBy` but I am encountering several issues.

If the extered expreesion is `1+2`
Then I should get`ExprAdd (ExprNum 1) (ExprNum 2)`

I am unable to proceed further from here .Help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: `sepBy` is too naive. Try searching for left factoring. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588019/how-to-build-parser-in-haskell/26588465#26588465, maybe someone from your class?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be writing a parser with parser combinators you need to think in terms of high-level rules first. Here's a skeleton parser in Parsec; it **does not** 100% meet your needs because all of the operators are same-precedence and right-associative, whereas you probably want different precedences and left-associativity. Still, this is the basic way to write a parser:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Data.Char (isDigit)

-- basic data type
data Expr = Op Char Expr Expr | N Integer deriving (Show)
type Parser x = Parsec String () x

-- reverse-sequenced >>, used to implement `parenthesized` and `whitespaced`
(<<) :: Monad m => m x -> m y -> m x
mx << my = mx >>= \x -> my >> return x
infixl 1 <<

parenthesized :: Parser e -> Parser e
parenthesized e = char '(' >> e << char ')'

whitespaced :: Parser e -> Parser e
whitespaced e = spaces >> e << spaces

number :: Parser Expr
number = do
    c <- oneOf "123456789" -- leading 0's can be reserved for octal/hexadecimal
    cs <- many digit
    return (N (read (c:cs)))

operator :: Parser Expr
operator = do
    e1 <- expr_no_op
    o <- whitespaced (oneOf "+*/-")
    e2 <- expression
    return (Op o e1 e2)

expr_no_op :: Parser Expr
expr_no_op = whitespaced (try number <|> parenthesized expression)

expression :: Parser Expr
expression = whitespaced (try operator <|> try number <|> parenthesized expression)
```

Notice that you define tokens (above, just 'number') and then combine them with a "try this `<|>` try that `<|>` otherwise..." syntax. Notice also that you **have** to stop `operator` from taking an expression as its first argument otherwise you'll get a `operator -> expression -> operator` loop in the parsing. This is called "left factoring."